# What type of plug is this?

Tags: prusa-i3, hotend, electronics, replacement-parts, bq-hephestos

I'm not really sure what the type of plug on the heater cable is. Is it a Molex KK or maybe a JST PH?

The printer is a *Prusa I3* Hephestos (aka BQ Hephestos). It came with this "BQ HOT-END HEATCORE CLASSIC" hotend from the "BQ Witbox 1" extruder.

[image: Hotend in question]

Comment: Done. But why should this help identifying the plug? If someone knows the molex or JST plug the image should be enough I think.

Comment: It might help someone with access to documentation for that printer look up the answer for you. Then again, it might not - but additional, relevant information is usually helpful. Welcome to the site, and please take the [tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: The cable of the heater element uses a "JST male connector 2.5 mm pitch". According to the seller of the heater element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As 0scar noted, this looks suspiciously *like* a JST connector, but the left one is not a JST RCY connector and it is neither one of the common [JST PH](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=199) nor [JST XH](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=277), JST manufacturer pages show. In fact, it's not a [wire-to-wire JST](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/search_e.php?type=1&id=11&page=1) connector. The [BQ-store claims](https://www.bqstore.nl/de/bq/77-BQ-Heizpatrone-40W-mit-JST-Stecker-8436545516805.html) it is a 2.5 mm JST connector, but JST has some 10 dozen different types of connectors, some three dozen of them with a 2.5 mm pitch.

### "JST Quick" / JST RCY

[image]

This one is rated 3A, and looks like the connector on the right, the thermistor one. So if you need to fix that, you know what to get for that.

### So what it is?

The connector however looks at *first glance suspiciously* like this one:
[image]

I found this product on several warehouses, listed as `2-PIN CONNECTOR W/HEADER, .10"`, and even found a [specsheet](https://www.allelectronics.com/mas_assets/media/allelectronics2018/spec/CON-242.pdf). Those products appear, in design, to be based on the [**Molex KK 254**](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/part-detail/crimp_houaings/0022013027) from the 2659 series. A genuine Molex 2659-series connector is rated for up to [**2.5 Ampere**](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/ps/PS-10-07-001.pdf), and looks *somewhat* similar.

However, the shop did claim it is a JST 2.5 mm pin, and they give a side view:

[image]

That is **not** a Molex KK. It appears more similar to a JST NV, which however has a 5 mm distance between the peg centers (= pitch) and it's rated for 10 A (or 120 W at 12V!). While matching in *style* it does not match in measurements - as OP confirmed, there's a very close to a 4 mm pitch (+- measurement tollerance) on the connector. So it's not an NV, but something os similar style.

[image]

But then it has to be the VH! The VH series has a 3.98 mm pitch, it has that latch and it is rated 10 A, for 120 W at 12 V. In fact, the pins on the Hotend seem to be B2P-VH, matching VHR-2N or VHR-2M "female" adapters.

[image]

#### Safety?

I would **not** trust a Molex KK 2659-series connector with a heater cartridge on a 12 V Machine! With a 12 V, 30 W Heater cartridge draws **exactly** 2.5 Ampere, so you'd have a safety margin of 0! That's bad design. A 40 W heater cartridge would draw 3.3 A - that's 132 % of the rating! That'd be a fire waiting to happen!

Only a 24 V machine could be built with a Molek KK 2659 connector and stay within the 2.5 A rating (40 W & 24 V -> 1.67 A, 30 W & 24 W -> 1.25 A) with a safety factor of about 1.5 to 2 to the rating (depending on heater cartridge).

However, this is a JST VH with a rating of 10 A. That means, at 12 V, it's safe for 120 W load, so plenty safe: That's a safety facor of 3, and on a 24 V machine it'd be 6. That's Perfectly safe and sane! After all we look for at least a 5 A rated connector in conjunction with a 12 V/40 W heater.

The more tedious variant to connect safely is to use either an even higher rated connector (requiring replacement) or a continuous wire to the board.